# SSRS report variable access and changing

Tags: reporting-services

I want to toggle visibility of a table in a report by clicking on a chart. I can hide initially and then display easily enough, but I want to toggle the display. I created a report variable atied the table visibility to that. So far, so good. Then I put an expression in a parameter that calls the report again hoping to change the report var for the toggle. No luck. I get the error that the report var is read only even though I checked that off.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Stab at a code function

```
Public Function ShowData() as Boolean

if report.parameters!rvDisplay.Value = true

    report.parameters!rvDisplay.Value = false

else

    report.parameters!rvDisplay.Value = true

end if

return report.parameters!rvDisplay.Value

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Your way is a bit too complicated.

<strike>Select the table that you want hidden and open the Properties pane. Scroll down and find the Hidden property - next to it there'll be a property called "ToggleItem" - set that to be your Chart, and you should then be able to toggle the hidden state of the table by clicking the chart.</strike>

Comment: Not possible. Toggle items only "look" at fields in the same scope, i.e., the same table. Can't reference the chart object.